# Adjusting size of popup window

Tags: swift, macos, nsviewcontroller

I'd like to build a modal dialog window that contains a number of NSViews, where it isn't known at compile time how many views to display.  I've been able to populate a window with views, but two issues are holding me up.  One is adjusting the size of the window depending on how many items are to be displayed.  Another post will address the other issue.

I use a storyboard to create a window with "OK" and "Cancel" buttons, then I add to the contents of the window

Here are the essential parts of my code:

```
class ParmViewController: NSViewController {

    static func showParmDialog()
    {
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "ParmViewController") as! NSWindowController
        let window = windowController.window!
        let viewController = window.contentViewController as! ParmViewController
        viewController.setup()
        let application = NSApplication.shared
        application.runModal(for: window)
        window.close()
    }
    let newHeight:CGFloat = 240        
    func setup() {
        print( view.frame )        // prints (0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 180.0)
        view.frame = NSRect( x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: newHeight )
        print( view.frame )        // prints (0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 240.0)
    }
}
```

The above code has no effect on the displayed size of the window.  The view has a superview, whih is 22 pixels taller than this window -- adjusting its size also has no effect.

How can I adust the window size on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Resizing works if I move the code to `viewDidLoad()`.